# It looks like my dog had his third epileptic seizure. Should I do anything about it?

Tags: dogs

Last night my beagle started trembling and could barely stand on its legs. It urinated on the sofa as it happened. This was over in about 10 minutes and the dog returned to normal, but it looked tired.

It seems this has happened three times in its seven-year life.

The only thing we could do was to treat it with gentleness. Is there anything more we could do?

Comment: You should try a vet. My sister's miniature schnauzer was (fairly badly) epileptic. He had daily medication for it. When he had a fit, she did the same as you, care and gentleness. Your dog sounds better (I.e. fewer fits) but you should see a professional so you can make an informed choice about how best to treat this.

Comment: Epileptics could change over time (how often and how hard) so you should visit the vet minimum because of the possibility it gets harder! You could get an emergency medicine for example to relax muscles until a very hard event.

Answer (score 4):

Imagine it was you having the seizure. Would you see a doctor? My guess is you would.

Your dog **needs** to be seen by a veterinarian. This could be an easily correctable condition or a life-threatening one.

Be a good human and take proper care of a life that depends upon your good judgement.

Comment: He has been to see a vet who just said it's not surprising for the race. He said that given it happens every two years we should leave him alone.

Comment: I’m glad to hear he has seen a vet but I think a second opinion is in order. At the very least, bloodwork and an anti convulsive or benzo seem in prudent. The “electrical brain storm” can cause serious injury in and of itself. If it concerns you enough to post about, I would think it’s important to follow up on and find a course of action to help your doggo.